# Whats the proper way to do Rspec with files or images on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm doing an application that needs an upload of images that will later be displayed on another view but so far I haven't found the proper way to test it through a feature using Rspec with Capybara

this is the code a want to test

```
<%= f.label :photo, "Foto"%>
<%= f.file_field :photo%><br>
```

[image]

as an user seeing the page a I want to simulate the action of adding a photo or a file so it will be displayed like this

```
<dt>Foto</dt>
<dd><%= image_tag @applicant.photo %></dd>
```

Comment: Show the relevant generated HTML rather than erb so we can see the HTML ids, etc

Comment: the view is not really the part that is important for me to know I'm more into knowing how to test the filling of the form, but just wait a bit and I'll update the whole thing.

Comment: I didn’t ask to see the view, I asked to see the relevant HTML. The generated HTML would show the generated (from the erb) ids, classes, etc. allowing me to give you a complete answer to your question.

Comment: sorry you meant this ? 
```<label for="applicant_photo">Foto</label>
<input type="file" name="applicant[photo]" id="applicant_photo" /><br>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Capybara you can upload files via file inputs using the `attach_file` method - https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method
The method takes a locator which is matched against the file input fields id, name,  placeholder, associated labels text, etc. There are also a few other more specific options you can pass (see documentation). In your case that means any of

```
attach_file('applicant_photo', '/path/to/file/to/attach') # id
attach_file('applicant[photo]', '/path/to/file/to/attach') # name attribute
attach_file('Foto', '/path/to/file/to/attach') # associated label text
```

should work for you. Technically on a page that only has one visible file input field you could also just do

```
attach_file('/path/to/file/to/attach') # will use the only file input on page
```

`attach_file` also has a block accepting mode for use when the file input field is non-visible and the label is styled to give a more modern UI but that doesn't currently apply to your use case.